# Ayuda con Matriz por Vector

Tags: java

de nuevo molestando, tengo este problemita de mutliplicar una matriz con un vector, por el momento lo maneje con esas filas y columnas antes de hacer la de 5x5, no puedo resolverlo del todo, ya tengo algo de avance.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  public class MxV {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[][] m1 = {{1,0,2},{-1,3,1}};
            int fil_m1 = m1.length;
    int col_m1 = m1[0].length;

            int[] v = {3,2,1};
    int fil_m2 = v.length;
    int col_m2 = 1;

    if (col_m1 != fil_m2)
        throw new RuntimeException("No se pueden multiplicar las matrices");

    // nueva matriz de filas de M1 y columnas de M2
    int[][] multiplicacion = new int[fil_m1][col_m2];

    for (int x=0; x < multiplicacion.length; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < multiplicacion[x].length; y++) {

                // El nuevo bucle suma la multiplicación de la fila por la columna
                for (int z=0; z<col_m1; z++) {
                    multiplicacion [x][y] += m1[x][z]*v[z];

                }

                             System.out.println("la matriz resultante es: "+multiplicacion);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Cual es el error que se presenta?,

Comment: no me imprime la otra nueva matriz y me arroja caracteres y otros numeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente solución (aunque se puede mejorar de muchas maneras, por ejemplo sacando el cálculo de la matriz resultado a un método). Lo primero que he hecho es crearme unos métodos para visualizar la matriz original, el vector y la matriz resultado.

Después hay que tener en cuenta que la matriz resultado va a tener el tamaño siguiente:

```
int[][] multiplicacion = new int[fil_m1][col_m1];
```

He simplificado el bucle. Sólo tenemos que hacer una operación por cada elemento de la matriz.

Finalmente llamó al método para visualizar el resultado del ejercicio.

Código:

```
public class MxV {

    private static void renderizarMatriz(int[][] matriz) {
        for (int x=0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.println("posicion[" + x + "][" + y + "]: " + matriz[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void renderizarVector(int[] matriz) {
        for (int x=0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
            System.out.println("posicion[" + x + "]: " + matriz[x]);
        }
    }

    private static void visualizarResultadoEjercicio(int[][]matrizOriginal, int[] vector, int[][] matrizResultado) {
        System.out.println("La matriz original es la siguiente: ");
        renderizarMatriz(matrizOriginal);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("El vector es el siguiente");
        renderizarVector(vector);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("La matriz resultado es la siguiente: ");
        renderizarMatriz(matrizResultado);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] m1 = {{1,0,2},{-1,3,1}};
        int fil_m1 = m1.length;
        int col_m1 = m1[0].length;

        int[] v = {3,2,1};
        int fil_m2 = v.length;

        if (col_m1 != fil_m2)
            throw new RuntimeException("No se pueden multiplicar las matrices");

        // nueva matriz de filas de M1 y columnas de M2
        int[][] multiplicacion = new int[fil_m1][col_m1];

        // Recorremos la matriz original
        for (int x=0; x < m1.length; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y < m1[x].length; y++) {
                // Por cada posición de la matriz original debemos realizar una multiplicación con el elemento correspondiente del vector
                multiplicacion[x][y] = m1[x][y] * v[y]; 
            }
        }

        visualizarResultadoEjercicio(m1, v, multiplicacion);
    }

}
```

Y esto es la visualización del resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho para comprender el ejercicio, seguire practicando

Answer (score 1):

Lo llamas vector, pero lo programas como otra matriz.

- Tienes una matriz de 2 dimensiones, cuyas filas son iguales a otra matriz de 1 dimensión.
- Tienes esa segunda matriz de 1 dimensión, con 1 única columna y tantas filas como la primera.
- Tienes una tercera matriz de exactamente las mismas dimensiones que la primera, pero vacía y preparada para almacenar valores.

Para cada fila de la primera matriz, multiplicas cada columna por la misma fila de la segunda matriz, y el resultado lo guardas en la misma posición que la primera matriz con la que estás trabajando.

sólo te hace falta recorrer la tercera matriz, y a cada posición darle como valor la operación de esa misma posición pero de la primera matriz, multiplicado por el valor de la misma fila que hay en la segunda matriz.

2 for (1 for dentro de otro) y una operación de multiplicación. Esta es la dificultad que tiene este problema.

Si te lías en el manejo de 2 o 3 matrices simultáneamente, simplemente haz previamente a este problema otros problemas que trabajen con 1 única matriz, rellenándola y leyéndola. Cuando ya operes bien con 1 única matriz podrás enfrentarte a este problema. No te costará mucho. con 2 o 3 ejercicios de rellenado y de leído de 1 única matriz estarás preparado. Ej: Rellena una matriz de 9x9 con los valores de un sudoku resuelto que encuentres por ahí. Después muestra los valores por pantalla, en 9 filas y 9 columnas. Y con 2-3 ejercicios más de este tipo ya podrás enfrentarte a este.

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando variables un poco forzadas. El ciclo con la variable `z` es innecesario y además se presta para inconsistencias. Además estás sumándole al campo de la matriz `multiplicacion` el valor del producto cuando simplemente deberías hacer la asignación sin sumárselo a nada, para evitar aún más inconsistencias.

Te estás complicando más de la cuenta, aquí te corrijo un poco el código:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[][] m1 = {{1,0,2},{-1,3,1}};
    int[] v = {
            3,
            2,
            1
    };

    if(m1.length != v.length)
        throw new RuntimeException("No se puede multiplicar la matriz con el vector: longitudes incongruentes.");

    int[][] multiplicacion = new int[m1.length][];
    for (int fila = 0; fila < m1.length; fila++) {
        multiplicacion[fila] = new int[m1[fila].length];
        for (int columna = 0; columna < m1[fila].length; columna++) {
            multiplicacion[fila][columna] = m1[fila][columna] * v[fila];
        }
    }

    //Imprime la matriz resultante
    for (int x=0; x < multiplicacion.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < multiplicacion[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.print("[" + multiplicacion[x][y] + "]");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, te agradezco la guia, seguire practicando.